# How to use Oracle database as web service provider with JSON?

Tags: json, database, oracle, web-services, plsql

I'm considering an option to use Oracle Database as web services provider and implement web service logic via PL/SQL stored procedures. I used to code stored procedures some time ago, though I'm not sure what direction should I go in order to use most up to date solutions:

1. I would like to use amazon cloud for oracle solution. After creating oracle instance, what else should be done in order to use it for serving as web server. I didn't find Amazon Cloud for Oracle  Application Server or Glassfish. Also, I need to use JSON but it's unclear does Oracle have such support out of the box. Currently, I found the only option to use [Soap 1.1 with Oracle XML DB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chtwelve.htm#CBBEDIDD)
2. Should there be two DB instances for security issues: one node serving as data source and the other one serving as web service provider.

Would appreciate for any ideas and info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to review the [Oracle Rest Data Services Developer Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/documentation/listener-dev-guide-1979546.html)

Amazon provides Oracle access in their product "RDS", but I've never tried it. However, I doubt that you'd be able to use the Oracle web listener directly.

JSON support is not included in Oracle AFAIK, but it should be easy to implement on your own.

---

Comment: Please see my detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440645/installing-oracle-rest-data-services-ords-on-tomcat