# ORDS and Tomcat - images prefix path might not be correct

Tags: java, tomcat, oracle-apex-5

I have installed JDK, Tomcat 8 and ORDS on the server. I installed ORDS as standalone and then copied the `images` folder to `j` folder undet `Tomcat dir/webapps`

I am getting the following error when trying to access `http:\localhost:8090\ords

> There is a problem with your environment because the Application Express files have not been loaded. Please verify that you have copied the images directory to your application server as instructed in the Installation Guide. In addition, please verify that your image prefix path is correct. Your current path is /j/ (it should contain both starting and ending forward slashes, such as the default /i/). Use the SQL script reset_image_prefix.sql if you need to change it

First I have noticed that my ORDS `standalone.properties` file did not have an ending `\` at the end of the path so I added it but still getting the same error.

Also another developer used /j/ instead of /i/ and I am  thinking it might be a problem but then I created /i/ directory and changed `standalone.properties` but nothing has changed - still getting an error.

My database is on another server and I assume so is the script `reset_image_prefix.sql`. I might not be able to run it myself, will have to ask a DBA but maybe that is not the problem and I can make a change on my own on the current server?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! The issue was that `images` folder copied was not complete, so once we copied `images` folder that had all the files

Answer (score 1):

@ElenaDBA, could you please answer me the following questions?

1. Version of ords?
2. Are you migrating the Apex or is a fresh installation?
3. Is it a prod or the dev installation?
4. Is your database PDB or not?

I will provide the solution according to your answer?

Here are the steps without using SQL Developer?

1. Install java 7+ and TOMCAT
2. Setup JAVA_HOME
3. Make sure tomcat is configured correctly by running the tomcat server without **ords.war**.
4. Create user for ORDS users

> ```
> ALTER USER APEX_PUBLIC_USER identified by password123 ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
> create USER ORDS_PUBLIC_USER identified by password123; 
> alter USER ORDS_PUBLIC_USER identified by password123 ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
> grant connect to ORDS_PUBLIC_USER;
> ```

5. create folders /opt/ords/war_file /opt/ords/config
6. download ords.war into /opt/ords/war_file folder
7. create directory /opt/ords/config
8. execute the following:

   cd /opt/ords/war_file
   java -jar ords.war
   You will be prompted for the oracle database server name, SID, sysdba user password.

> Say NO or SKIP to apex installation.

9. copy /opt/ords/war_file/ords.war to /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat/webapps/ folder
10. run tomcat and browse to

    http://server-ip:8080/ords

you should get the ords page with **404 Not Found**

11. ORDS is installed and up and running. Now its time to enable some schema and its object.

**Enable Schema:**

```
BEGIN
 ORDS.ENABLE_SCHEMA(p_enabled => TRUE,
   p_schema => '<schema-name>',
   p_url_mapping_type => 'BASE_PATH',
   p_url_mapping_pattern => '<schema-alias>',
   p_auto_rest_auth => FALSE);
commit;
END;
/
```

**Enable Object/Table:**

```
BEGIN
 ORDS.ENABLE_OBJECT(p_enabled => TRUE,
   p_schema => '<schema-name>',
   p_object => '<table-name>',
   p_object_type => 'TABLE',
   p_object_alias => '<table-alias-name>',
   p_auto_rest_auth => FALSE);
 commit;
END;
/
```

12. Now browse to

http://server-ip:8080/ords/schema-alias/table-alias

13. To Disable Schema

> ```
> BEGIN
>      ORDS.ENABLE_SCHEMA(
>       p_enabled => FALSE,
>       p_schema => '<schema-name>');
> end;
> /
> ```

14. Uninstall ORDS

> ```
> cd /opt/ords/war_file
> java -jar ords.war uninstall
> ```

Comment: Would you like to install using SQL Developer or without SQL Developer? actually for dev it's very easy using SQL Developer.

Comment: No, I do not even have SQL Developer installed. I installed it using ords.war file

Comment: That's cool. You can follow the steps mentioned above and let me know your results.

Comment: that is exactly what we did. So we set config directory, then ran setup and then dropped the ords.war file into webapps directory in Tomcat. Tomcat installed the ords and then we went to http://loclahost:8080/ords and gotten the error in question

Comment: First, As I said above, you don't need those apex images, you can just ignore it. Second, don't use standalone mode.

Comment: I did not use standalone mode. Just to recap my steps: i had Java JDK and Tomcat 8 already installed. So I downloaded and unzipped ords, then ran `java -jar ords.war configdir C:\...\ords...\config` , followed by `java -jar ords.war setup`. then we entered all the data we were prompted for, such as server name, port, service name, etc. Then, after that was done we dropped `ords.war` into Tomcat `webapps` folder. Ords gotten installed on Tomcat. So we tested it by going to `http:\\localhost:8080\ords` and then we got the error

Comment: P.S. Images already have been copied into `webapps\j' folder before the ORDS installation ran.

Comment: Then your next step is to enable your schema and the table as a rest endpoint. Follow the steps #11 and #12. You are getting the error till that step has nothing problem. By the way your url should be ``httt://localhost:8080/ords`` instead of ``http:\\localhost:8080\ords``

Comment: The issue was resolved! The problem was some missing files and folders from apex images folder

Comment: Great news...I had already said the same that you don't need those file to run ORDS. Anyway, please accept and upvote my answer if you would thought that it was helpful for you.

Comment: If we really didn't need those files, why would we get that error? i will upvote the useful answers. Could you please help me with my other question?

Comment: from ORDS 3.x+ you don't need apex installation. Apex is the old name for ORDS. If you have old Apex system then you can migrate using those files, but since you are not doing that you can install without it. I have deployed the ORDS 3.x without apex. I am just sharing my experience with you.

Comment: but it did not work without copying apex images folder

Comment: then something is missing in installation steps. See the steps above where I have not mention anywhere to copy apex file.